# Ler arquivo de texto e jogar o conteúdo em posições em um array!

Tags: php, array

Estou em dúvida em poder ler um arquivo `.txt` e armazenar os seus dados em diferentes posições em um `array`.

Sendo que o arquivo é salvo da seguinte maneira:

```
city=A(100,80);
city=B(160,70);
city=C(110,50);
city=D(140,120);
city=F(155,40);
city=G(210,60);
city=H(190,10);
city=I(170,110);
route=A-C;140;
route=A-D;155;
route=C-F;125;
route=D-B;115;
route=D-I;152;
route=B-F;119;
route=B-G;136;
route=G-F;133;
route=F-H;163;
route=I-H;197;
```

E gostaria de ler ele e armazenar ele separadamente nas posições de um `array`.

```
<?php

$f = fopen("mapa.txt", "r");

while (!feof($f)) { 
     $arrM = explode(";",fgets($f)); 
}

fclose($f);

?>
```

Nesse exemplo, ele está armazenando ele todo dentro de uma única posição!
E no caso gostaria que fosse armazenado assim:

```
$arrM[0] = city=A(100,80);
$arrM[1] = city=B(160,70);
$arrM[2] = city=C(110,50);
//.....

$arrM[] = route=A-C;140;
```

Comment: E quais são os critérios? cada linha do arquivo numa posição do array?

Comment: Os critérios seriam: 
$arrM[0] = city=A(100,80);
$arrM[1] = city=B(160,70);
$arrM[2] = city=C(110,50);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue abaixo outra forma usando o [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) e [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$linhas = explode("\n", file_get_contents('mapa.txt'));

echo $linhas[0] . "\n"; // city=A(100,80);
echo $linhas[1] . "\n"; // city=B(160,70);
echo $linhas[2] . "\n"; // city=C(110,50);
echo $linhas[9] . "\n"; // route=A-D;155;
```

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu estava precisando !! Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Se o arquivo não for muito grande, pode usar a função `file()` ela vai converter o seu arquivo em um array.

```
$f = file("mapa.txt");
foreach($f as $item){
   echo $item .'<br>';
}
```

Comment: no caso do file(), é possível usar um delimitador para separar ele conforme a minha ultima edição da pergunta? @rray

Comment: @LuizFelipe Não da para simplesmente fazer `echo $f[0];`?